# I want a javascript regular expression which accepts only numbers 0 or 0.0 / 0.5 / 1 or 1.0 /1.5 /2 or 2.0/ 2.5 / 3 or 3.0 /3.5 /4 or 4.0/ 4.5 / 5

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a javascript regular expression which accepts only numbers

```
0 or 0.0 / 0.5 / 1 or 1.0 /1.5 /2 or 2.0/ 2.5 / 3 or 3.0 /3.5 /4 or 4.0/ 4.5 / 5
```

I'm using the below expression, it works fine but the only condition it fails when i give 5.0 or 5.1 or 5.2 or 5.3 or 5.4 or 5.5:

```
var regOrderNo = /^[0-5]+(\.[05])?$/;
```

I want a regular expression that should not allow decimal after number 5

Comment: var regOrderNo = /^[0-5]+(\.[05])?$/;

Comment: You can edit your question when you click on the "edit" link.

Comment: Did you look at the lookbehind approach of regex?

Comment: @Neeraj: JavaScript does not support lookbehinds (but otherwise good idea).

Comment: Sorry , but im not good in regular expression. I got this regular expression also from one of the site

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good site to learn more about it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regOrderNo = /^(5|[0-4](\.[05])?)$/;
```

Since you don't want 5 to be treated like the others, you need to have a separate case for it.

Also, note that the `+` is gone.  Your regex could have matched 123123123.5.  You want to make sure there's only one digit.